# How do a save Unity3d Mesh to file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At runtime I create a Mesh. I would like to save this so it's an asset in my project so I don't have to re-create it every time.

How can I save a Mesh created at run-time into my Asset folder?

Comment: a very useful trick is: just start with something in your Assets that has a trivial mesh (make it in Cheetah3D ... just a box, whatever).  Now instead of starting from scratch, use that as a basis - erase all the verts and start from scratch. In fact save and it actually rewrites the asset.  It's an incredibly time-saving trick - it saves you all the nonsense setup code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use that Mesh Serializer: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MeshSerializer2

```
public static void CacheItem(string url, Mesh mesh)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, url);
    byte [] bytes = MeshSerializer.WriteMesh(mesh, true);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
}
```

It won't save into the Asset folder since this one does not exist anymore at runtime. You would most likely save it to the persistent data path, which is meant to store data, actually.

Then you can retrieve it just going the other way around:

```
public static Mesh GetCacheItem(string url)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, url);
    if(File.Exists(path) == true)
    {
        byte [] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return MeshSerializer.ReadMesh(bytes);
    }
    return null;
}
```